# How to remove border around QGraphicsItem when selected?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem

Pretty basic question but I couldn't find a solution through google. In QT when a graphics item is selected, there's a border around it. I was wondering how I can set this border to be invisible. Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's no interface to disable the drawing of the selection border for the build-in QGraphicsItems. The only way I can think of is derive your own items from the build-in ones and override the `paint()` function:

```
void MyRectItem::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    QStyleOptionGraphicsItem myOption(*option);
    myOption.state &= ~QStyle::State_Selected;
    QGraphicsRectItem::paint(painter, &myOption, widget);
}
```

It's not tested but basically you make a copy of option passed and clear the selection state flag before passing it to the actual `paint()`.

Comment: Stephen. I will try this when I get home. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work in Qt 5.15, but `myOption.state = QStyle::State_None;` seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 7):

If your QGraphicsItem is derived from QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem then you can simply disable its pen, example:

```
myShape->setPen(Qt::NoPen);
```

Answer (score 2):

for those trying to figure it out using python:

```
def paint(self, painter, option, a):
    option.state = QStyle.State_None
    return super(MyClassName, self).paint(painter,option)
```

Comment: PyQt6: `option.state = QStyle.StateFlag.State_None`